# Reference request: fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, free-groups

I am loking for a reference to the following fact

The fundamental group of a non-closed surface is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces). It's about the noncompact case, but that suffices for your question because any non-closed surface is homotopy equivalent to its interior, which is a noncompact surface.

Comment: Is it obvious that a non-compact surface with boundary is homotopy equivalent to its interior?

Comment: It's pretty obvious. Some neighborhood $U$ of $\partial S$ with closure $\overline U$ can be collared, meaning there is a homeomorphism $\overline U \approx\partial S \times [0,1]$ such that $U \approx \partial S \times (0,1]$. Using this collaring, the inclusion map of $S - \partial S \hookrightarrow S$ has a homotopy inverse which is the identity on $S-U$ and which, on $\partial S \times [0,1]$, is the map $(x,t) \mapsto (x,t/2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!